# undefined method `id' for #<Property::ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

Sorry for dumb question

Here when I am raising `@property` I am getting row but when I am raising `@property.id` it's showing `undefined method id` give me conclusion about this

in `owner.rb`

```
has_many :properties
```

in `property.rb`

```
belongs_to :owner
```

in owners_controller.rb

```
def new    
user = User.friendly.find(current_user.slug)
@owner = user.owner
authorize @owner
@property = Property.where(owner_id: @owner)
#raise @property.id.inspect
@renter = User.friendly.find(params[:renter_id]).renter  
@message = Message.new(renter_id: @renter.id, owner_id: @owner.id,property_id: @property.id)
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `where`returns an `AR relation` which is an `array`.Try `@property.first.id`

Comment: Or replace `where` with `find_by`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said, `where` returns an `Active Record` relation which is an `array`. Try the below

```
raise @property.first.id
```

**or**

Change this

```
@property = Property.where(owner_id: @owner)
```

to

```
@property = Property.find_by(owner_id: @owner)
```